# Javascript scrollIntoView only in immediate parent

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make `scrollIntoView` only scroll the immediate parent (e.g. `div` with `overflow-y: scroll;`) and not the whole page?

I have a web interface I'm making for an internal, very-specific purpose. Among other elements on my page is a `div` with a specified height and `overflow-y` is `scroll`.

I have data which will periodically appear in this area and I want it to always be scrolled to the bottom (e.g. the console output of a subprocess on some remote server).

If I use `scrollIntoView`, it scrolls the `overflow-y` `div`..... but also scrolls the whole page.

On a computer with a large monitor, this isn't an issue, but on my laptop with a smaller screen it also scrolls the whole window, which is definitely *not* the intended/desired behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for a combination of `scrollTop` and `scrollHeight`. You can use the first to set where you want the div to scroll to, and the second to get the height of all the info in the div:

```js
var scrollyDiv = document.getElementById("container");
scrollyDiv.scrollTop = scrollyDiv.scrollHeight

setInterval(() => {
  var textnode = document.createElement("P");
  textnode.innerHTML = "Whatever"
  scrollyDiv.appendChild(textnode);  
  scrollyDiv.scrollTop = scrollyDiv.scrollHeight
}, 1000)
```

```css
#container {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#big-content {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="big-content"></div>
  <p>The bottom</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 56):

I think what you might be looking for is

```
.scrollIntoView({block: "nearest", inline: "nearest"});
```

Where supported (basically anywhere except IE and SafarIE) this will do the 'least' movement to show the element; so if the outer container is visible, but the target element is hidden inside that container -- then it should scroll the inner container but not the page.

Comment: This example worked for me using Microsoft Edge.  I have a custom styled dropdown list.  When the dropdown expands, the div that contains the options scrolls vertically.  Using this example, only that div scrolls so that the currently selected option is visible, and the other antecedent elements do not scroll.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: sound like inline is nearest by default?

Comment: Yes, the current spec has nearest as default. `scrollIntoViewArgs` are still in draft, so it seemed reasonable to make the setting explicit. Remove as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for React 16**

Here is an answer for this problem using React 16, for people who want to have a scrollable element scroll to its bottom upon some event. I was having the problem that scrollIntoView() was causing the whole window to adjust, which was undesirable; just need the scrolling element to scroll to the bottom (like a terminal) on demand.

Add a ref to the element with `overflowY: "scroll"`, and use the formula `this.body.current.scrollTo(0, this.body.current.scrollHeight)` like so:

```js
constructor() {
    ...
    this.body = React.createRef() // Create a ref to your scrollable element
}
...

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) { // or whatever action you want
    // The Important Part, where you scroll to the y-coord 
    // that is the total height, aka the bottom. 
    // .current is important, as you want the version of 
    // that ref that is rendered right now.
    this.body.current.scrollTo(0, this.body.current.scrollHeight) 
    ...
}
...
render() {
   return (
      <div style={style.container}>
            <div ref={this.body} style={style.body}> // React ref tagged here
            ....
            </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your case and I think that `scrollIntoView()` will not work as you wish. Try to use `scrollTop` instead.
Hope it will save your time.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('js-scroll');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const targets = document.querySelectorAll('.scrollable');
  
  targets.forEach(t => {
    // Scroll each item
    t.scrollTop = t.scrollHeight;
  });
});
```

```css
.scroll-btn {
  position:fixed;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 35px 10px;
}

.scrollable {
  margin: 15px; 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.scrollable-data {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  min-height: 600px;
  background-color: #55b7ab;
}
```

```html
<button id="js-scroll" class="scroll-btn">Scroll</button>

<section class="content">
  <div class="scrollable">
    <div class="scrollable-data">Some data 1</div>
    <div class="scrollable-data">Some data 1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="scrollable">
    <div class="scrollable-data">Some data 2</div>
    <div class="scrollable-data">Some data 2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="scrollable">
    <div class="scrollable-data">Some data 3</div>
    <div class="scrollable-data">Some data 3</div>
  </div>
</section>
```